# How to convert a date from this format '31/1/19' to this format '1-31-2019' in Excel

Tags: excel, analytics, data-analysis, exploratory-data-analysis

I am doing an end to end Data Analytics project, for that I have a data set.

This data set has date column where many dates are in unstructured format (ie 31/1/19) how can I convert it into a standard format (ie 1-31-2019)

Comment: StackOverflow is not for Excel questions, You can ask the same on [SuperUser](https://superuser.com/)

Comment: Are you using Excel or Google Sheets?

Comment: @SidharthMudgil - certain questions regarding Excel *are* on topic for Stack Overflow. I would agree that this one is likely not though.

Comment: @BigBen yes questions like automating excel tasks and others are on-topic for StackOverflow but this is not.

Answer (score 0):

Through the Format menu on the top

[image]

Comment: If still having issues, please read how to and [share a test sheet](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/138383/117311) so as you can be easier helped. Also please choose: `Excel` OR `Google Sheets`?

Answer (score 0):

1. Select the cells you want to format.
2. Press CTRL+1.
3. In the Format Cells box, click the Number tab.
4. In the Category list, click Date and then choose a date format you
   want in Type.
5. Click OK

[Visit](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/format-a-date-the-way-you-want-8e10019e-d5d8-47a1-ba95-db95123d273e#:%7E:text=what%20you%20want.-,Select%20the%20cells%20you%20want%20to%20format.,format%20you%20want%20in%20Type.)

Comment: Actually I have tried this but I don't know why I'm not able to change any format of that column